# Maximum sum of n intervals in a sequence

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm doing some programming "kata" which are skill building exercises for programming (and martial arts). I want to learn how to solve for algorithms like these in shorter amounts of time, so I need to develop my knowledge of the patterns. Eventually I want to solve in increasingly efficient time complexities (O(n), O(n^2), etc), but for now I'm fine with figuring out the solution with any efficiency to start.

**The problem:**

Given arr[10] = [4, 5, 0, 2, 5, 6, 4, 0, 3, 5]

Given various segment lengths, for example one 3-length segment, and two 2-length segments, find the optimal position of (or maximum sum contained by) the segments without overlapping the segments.

For example, solution to this array and these segments is 2, because:

{4 5} 0 2 {5 6 4} 0 {3 5}

**What I have tried before posting on stackoverflow.com:**

I've read through:

[Algorithm to find maximum coverage of non-overlapping sequences. (I.e., the Weighted Interval Scheduling Prob.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026073/algorithm-to-find-maximum-coverage-of-non-overlapping-sequences-i-e-the-weig)

[algorithm to find longest non-overlapping sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593583/algorithm-to-find-longest-non-overlapping-sequences)

and I've watched MIT opencourseware and read about general steps for solving complex problems with dynamic programming, and completed a dynamic programming tutorial for finding Fibonacci numbers with memoization. I thought I could apply memoization to this problem, but I haven't found a way yet.

The theme of dynamic programming is to break the problem down into sub-problems which can be iterated to find the optimal solution.

What I have come up with (in an OO way) is

```
foreach (segment) {
    - find the greatest sum interval with length of this segment
```

This produces incorrect results, because not always will the segments fit with this approach. For example:

Given arr[7] = [0, 3, 5, 5, 5, 1, 0] and two 3-length segments,

The first segment will take 5, 5, 5, leaving no room for the second segment. Ideally I should memoize this scenario and try the algorithm again, this time avoiding 5, 5, 5, as a first pick. **Is this the right path**?

How can I approach this in a "dynamic programming" way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place the first segment, you get two smaller sub-arrays: placing one or both of the two remaining segments into one of these sub-arrays is a sub-problem of just the same form as the original one.

So this suggests a recursion: you place the first segment, then try out the various combinations of assigning remaining segments to sub-arrays, and maximize over those combinations. Then you memoize: the sub-problems all take an array and a list of segment sizes, just like the original problem.

I'm not sure this is the best algorithm but it is the one suggested by a "direct" dynamic programming approach.

EDIT: In more detail:

The arguments to the valuation function should have two parts: one is a pair of numbers which represent the sub-array being analysed (initially [0,6] in this example) and the second is a multi-set of numbers representing the lengths of the segments to be allocated ({3,3} in this example).  Then in pseudo-code you do something like this:

```
valuation( array_ends, the_segments):
    if sum of the_segments > array_ends[1] - array_ends[0]:
        return -infinity

    segment_length = length of chosen segment from the_segments
    remaining_segments = the_segments with chosen segment removed

    best_option = 0
    for segment_placement = array_ends[0] to array_ends[1] - segment_length:
         value1 = value of placing the chosen segment at segment_placement
         new_array1 = [array_ends[0],segment_placement]
         new_array2 = [segment_placement + segment_length,array_ends[1]]
         for each partition of remaining segments into seg1 and seg2:
             sub_value1 = valuation( new_array1, seg1)
             sub_value2 = valuation( new_array2, seg2)
             if value1 + sub_value1 + sub_value2 > best_option:
                  best_option = value1 + sub_value1 + sub_value2
    return best_option
```

This code (modulo off by one errors and typos) calculates the valuation but it calls the valuation function more than once with the same arguments.  So the idea of the memoization is to cache those results and avoid re-traversing equivalent parts of the tree.  So we can do this just by wrapping the valuation function:

```
memoized_valuation(args):
    if args in memo_dictionary:
         return memo_dictionary[args]
    else:
         result = valuation(args)
         memo_dictionary[args] = result
         return result
```

Of course, you need to change the recursive call now to call `memoized_valuation`.

Comment: Thanks this set me on the right path. For making those "various combinations", what about random number generator to make many decisions, and maximum that?

Comment: That wouldn't really be a "dynamic programming" approach.  First concentrate on making sure your algorithm tries every possibility.

Comment: How can I memoize this? First, the placements of segments goes to the highest value area. If the iteration consistently returns low numbers when a segment is placed in a particular area, then that would that be something to memoize? But, this seems like it would become a complicated mess. Which pieces should be memoized in general? In my Fibonacci sequence I placed numbers inside a hashtable. But here its more complicated because I may need note 2, 3, or more notes about a particular placement. I'm just not making the connection on what to keep track of and what to do with that information.

Comment: Memoize exactly the arguments to the recursive call.  But as you say, that is not a single number.  It is an array and a list of segments.  That can still form the key for a hash table.

Comment: I made it find the correct solution using random numbers, which I was excited about, but obviously that's bad and on sets of numbers > 20 it takes a long time. Now I'm focusing on memoizing.. I think I'm almost at the point where it is choosing every combination, but how do I maximize the result?
https://gist.github.com/fultonm/5e676fe7e1b0eb7f9e9a
The actual problem is actually the inverse of what I described, to minimize the threat on city blocks by placing patrols in highest threat areas, hence the metaphor in the code.